# How to catch error while parsing json without using if for each key?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, ios9

here is How i parse json:

```
let myObject = MyObject()
let string1 = if jsonObject["string1"] as? String{
    myObject.string1 = string1
}else{
  throw InValidJson
}

let string2 = if jsonObject["string2"] as? String{
    myObject.string2 = string2
}else{
  throw InValidJson
}

let string3 = if jsonObject["string3"] as? String{
    myObject.string3 = string3
}else{
  throw InValidJson
}
```

but that too much code, as i am using if every where, is it possible to do something like the following:

```
do{
   myObject.string1 = if jsonObject["string1"] as! String
   myObject.string2 = if jsonObject["string2"] as! String
   myObject.string3 = if jsonObject["string3"] as! String

}catch(){
   error.description
}
```

so i don't need to check every key, as my json is too large.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
guard let string1 = jsonObject["string1"] as? String,
  string2 = jsonObject["string2"] as? String,
  string3 = jsonObject["string3"] as? String else {
  //handle error
  return
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, is it possible to check which keys cause error